# Help needed finding a closed form for an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, closed-form

I would need help finding a closed form for this integral:

$$\int_2^\infty \frac{\ln(y-1)}{\ln(y)} - 1 +\frac{1}{y \ln(y)} dy$$

*My try:* I tried using series expansion with no result (I get a series with no closed form). Mathematica gives an approximated value, but no closed form either.

Any advice? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given integral equals
$$\int_{\log 2}^{+\infty}\frac{e^x \log(1-e^{-x})+1}{x}\,dx$$
that can be written as
$$ \int_{\log 2}^{+\infty} -\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{e^{-(n-1)x}}{nx}\,dx\stackrel{\mathcal{L}}{=}-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{ds}{2^{s+m}(s+m)(m+1)}$$
So it is pretty simple to approximate even with great accuracy, but I won't bet a penny on a simple closed form.

Comment: Thank you! I will wait to see if I receive any other answer before checking yours

Comment: Working with your last integral I got that it equals $$- \sum_{m \ge 1} \frac{\Gamma (0, m \log 2 )}{m+1} $$. Any hint about how to continue?

Comment: @user3141592: through asymptotics for the incomplete $\Gamma$ function, if you are interested in accurate approximations. As already said, I do not believe in the existence of a simple closed form.